# Sending multiple values from html to jquery for ajax process

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to send two variables to jquery file for further processing from one form.

html form

```
<a href="#"><img class="<?php 
 if($favorite == 1) { 
  echo 'alreadyfavorite';
 } else { 
  echo 'addtofavorite';} ?>" 
id="addtofavoritebutton" pid="<?php $data['property_id']?>" 
fpid="<?php $favorite_properties_id;?>" src="../images/system/addtofavorite.png"></a>
```

jquery

```
$('#addtofavoritebutton').click(function() {
  var property_id = $('#addtofavoritebutton').attr("pid");
  var favorite_properties = $('#addtofavoritebutton').attr("fpid");
  alert(property_id);
  alert(favorite_properties);
});
```

but the values are not getting picked up by jquery...

Comment: Does the image exist when you add the event handler?

Comment: does it enter the handler at all (i.e.: does it fire some alert, although empty)?

Comment: @elementzero23 Can you provide documentation link where it states that `.attr` is deprecated?

Comment: yes it was firing empty at .attr(), and with .prop() it is firing undefined for both variables

Comment: @Justinas you are right, it's not deprecated. But in most cases it's better to use `.prop()`:
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: you should use data-pid and data-fpid for your custom attribute names.

Comment: I've rebuilt the thing and it seems to work correctly... Are you sure you have values in those attributes?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML using the `<>` giving us a [mcve]

Comment: its working there is some other problem with php code... some loops are getting entangled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use ready function and put you jquery code in ready function**
**like:-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addtofavoritebutton').click(function() {
      var property_id = $('#addtofavoritebutton').attr("pid");
      var favorite_properties = $('#addtofavoritebutton').attr("fpid");
      alert(property_id);
      alert(favorite_properties);
    });
})
```

Comment: this is not working, the code above was already wrapped in $(document).ready(function(){ });

Comment: pid="<?php $data['property_id']?>"  shoud be pid="<?php echo $data['property_id']?>"

Comment: it was not picking up data because echo is required